# Raise an exception in parent thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have an issue where a method call is blocking and not releasing. Unfortunately, the bug as to why isn't exactly solvable, so the workaround at the moment is to build in a timeout.

I've tried to do this by registering a timer and have it raise an exception to break from the blocked call. However, that raises the exception in the timer thread, not the main thread.

It looks like this right now:

```
from threading import Timer

def timeoutSocket():
    raise InterruptedError


socketDeadlockDetector = Timer(DEADLOCK_TIMEOUT, timeoutSocket)
socketDeadlockDetector.start()

# receive and unpack data
try:
    packet = server.receive()
except InterruptedError:
    print("Interrupted socket receive, continuing")
    continue

socketDeadlockDetector.cancel()
```

`server.receive()` is the method that is blocking when it shouldn't. However, when I run this, the socketDeadlockDetector thread interrupts itself, without affecting the original thread.

Is there a way to pass this exception up to the parent?

Comment: What OS is this? Is it possible to have the receiving code use `select` to poll the socket rather than doing a blocking read? On some platforms, you *can't* wake up a blocking read on some kinds of devices ("uninterruptible wait" state).

Comment: It's a weird TCP bug where the socket is opened, the sender thinks the data is sent and as such closes the socket, but for whatever reason the receiver (server) isn't closing the socket, and hangs. It's not a socket timeout per se, so no socket Jiu Jitsu would be able to solve it afaik

Comment: Sounds like a socket half-close maybe? In any case, if your receiver uses `select.select()` in a loop, then it has an opportunity to run other code (like, e.g. check if a timeout expired) in between checking if there is more data to read from the socket.

Comment: Fair enough, I read up on that and now I see how it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Timer` creates a thread to run the function. It doesn't do you any good to raise an exception because that's not the thread needing interruption. When you hit the timeout, you need to cancel whatever is blocking in the other thread. In this case its a socket, so killing the socket should do.

```
import struct

def timeoutSocket():
    # enable linger with timeout 0 to send RESET on close
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, struct.pack('ii', 1, 0))
    server.close()
```